# How to read only the first value on each line of a .csv file in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to use a while loop to  put the first value of each line of a .csv file in C++ in a variable and print it right after that. The output is the first values of each line thus printed.

My data is (as in the .cssv file)

```
Mike,22,Student
James,54,Engineer
Lily,23,Student
```

I want to put the names in a variable in each iteration and then print it. My output is a list of these names only.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did it go wrong?

Comment: Use `std::getline()` to read a whole line, parse the 1st value and continue reading.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::stringstream` and `std::getline` to grab the first name, something like following:

```
std::string str;
std::vector <std::string> result;       // Vector of names

while( std::getline( std::cin, str ) )  // replace std::cin, with file input stream
{
    std::stringstream ss(str);
    if( ss.good() )
    {
        std::string substr;
        std::getline( ss, substr, ',' ); // Grab first names till first comma
        result.push_back( substr );      // Push into the vector
    }
}
```

[`Demo Here`](https://wandbox.org/nojs/gcc-7.2.0/permlink/ko2W7zMPDjYooVHQ)